# Animation of one part of object is not working

Tags: animation

The animation of all other parts like sheets cover of the album is working fine but the animation of the rings is not working

What is the reason for it, what is the rectification and how to avoid this form happening in future?

File Link -> https://blend-exchange.com/b/zD2aNDso

[image]

Comment: Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). You can use the [edit] button below to change you text into regular case.

Comment: What are you expecting to see? You're just rotating them in the Y direction and unless you apply some sort of pattern onto them you're not going to notice. I suspect that you really intend to move the Ring Side object, but you don't have any keyframes on that!

Comment: since you didn't write what you want....i assume John is right, and you want this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG1Vl.gif so just animate the ring side as John proposed. Nice animation btw...! ;)

Comment: @John Eason But i parented the ring side object with ring and then i had set the keyframes to the ring so as it is child to parent it has to move along with parent right or am i wrong. Please make me understand

Comment: No need to parent it at all. I'd just rotate the ring side and leave the rings alone. I guess you'd need to join (CTRL-J) the  ring side to the rings to get the whole object to rotate.

Comment: Actually I think you parented the rings to the ring side rather than the other way round. That does then work, but you'll need to change the angles to get the rotation correct.